# pymongo update_one syntax error

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

have a collection in mongodb called 'collection' and I need to do and upsert using pymongo.

```
collection.update_one({'_id': workflowID}, {
   '$set': {'repop': repop}, {'data': workflow__list()__}
}, upsert = True, multi = False)
```

but I get 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' with the little up arrow pointing under the 'o' in the repop object being stored as "repop".

I've looked at all the syntax in the world on this and this appears correct to me. Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of things wrong with your query.

- The [**`update_one`**](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) method doesn't have the `multi` option
- The update argument in your query should be:

  ```
  {'$set': {'repop': repop, 'data': workflow__list()__}}
  ```

Not

```
{'$set': {'repop': repop}, {'data': workflow__list()__}}
                       ^^^^^
```